# Why is a `Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: unsafe-none` header unsafe?

Tags: http, http-headers

We recently upgraded a web application to Django 4 which now, by default, adds a

`Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin`

header to http responses, which can cause `window.opener` to be `null` in the child window. This broke one of our pages where we had a child window (for SSO auth) sending a `postMessage()` back to the parent window when it was done doing its thing.

I know I can work around that by manually setting that header to `unsafe-none`, or structuring those pages differently, etc., but I'm curious what is potentially unsafe about the child window having access to `window.opener`?

Browsers keep `window.opener` pretty locked down, and there's not much that child windows can do with it other than calling `postMessage()` and a couple of other minor things.

Given that it is so locked down, what about it is unsafe?  **Can someone give an example of something damaging that a child window can do with `window.opener` *that the browser will allow*?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is briefly noted on MDN on the page about [noopener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types/noopener), which refers to [this blog post](https://mathiasbynens.github.io/rel-noopener/).

Directly quoting this blog:

> TL;DR If window.opener is set, a page can trigger a navigation in the opener regardless of security origin.

and

> This is a relatively harmless example, but instead it could’ve redirected to a phishing page, designed to look like the real index.html, asking for login credentials. The user likely wouldn’t notice this, because the focus is on the malicious page in the new window while the redirect happens in the background.

You should redesign the flow of the login, so that it does not need the unsafe header. Especially if you accept arbitrary links from users.

Comment: Wow, the browser won't allow the child window to _read_ `opener.location.href` (from my testing), but it will allow the child to change it?  That's crazy.  I'm surprised the browser allows that.